# Cardview in RecyclerView selects multi cards and not just one

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, cardview

I am creating a simple android app where cardview is created and inserted through a recycleview. I have added the possibility to select every single card, which changes the color of the text and makes it visible on the card. The problem is that when you click on the first card, the selection effect is also added to the last card, as if there were a bug for counting or something. Practically the first and last cards are connected, as if they were the same, as seen in the following images:

[1] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/NX9QO.jpg

[2] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/frxb9.jpg

I have not found any problem of this kind around, but I have already happened in the past to deal with problems like this in the interaction with cardview.
Here is my adapter with the code that does this:

```
public class AllMovesListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AllMovesListAdapter.UserViewHolder> {
private static CardView card;
private List<moveListActivity.move_card> moveList;
private static Context context;
int[] counter;

public AllMovesListAdapter(List<moveListActivity.move_card> biglList, Context context) {
    this.moveList = biglList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.move_card, null);
    UserViewHolder userViewHolder = new UserViewHolder(view);
    counter = new int[getItemCount()];
    return userViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final UserViewHolder holder, int position) {
    moveListActivity.move_card mcard = moveList.get(position);
    holder.tvName.setText(mcard.getName());
    holder.tvDescr.setText(mcard.getDescr());
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            if (position!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                if (counter[position]==0){
                    holder.ivTr.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.tvName.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.green));
                    holder.tvDescr.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.green));
                    counter[position]=1;
                }else{
                    holder.ivTr.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.tvName.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white));
                    holder.tvDescr.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white));
                    counter[position]=0;
                }
                Snackbar.make(v, "Click detected on item " + position + "| counter: " + counter[position],
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return moveList.size();
}

public static class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView ivMove, ivTr;
    TextView tvName;
    TextView tvDescr;

    public UserViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ivTr = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivTr);
        ivMove = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivMove);
        tvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        tvDescr = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescr);

    }
}
}
```

Does anyone know what this problem depends on? I would simply like to implement a multi-selection of the list of cards through this method. (I'm not sure that in the future I will deal with a few cardview, so I would like to use uan recyclerview rather than creating individual cards in the .xml file.

**EDIT:** Updated the code, as recommended by leojg. Move the onClick event management to onBindViewHolder. But the problem remains the same.

Comment: DId you find it? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the recycler view recycles the item position when it goes out of the screen.

You should move the onclick logic to the `onBindViewHolder()`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was trying, but I do not know what to call the setOnClickListener () function, it does not call me on the UserViewHolder holder

Comment: Cant you do somethings like holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(...)?

Comment: I also tried to do this, practically copying the content from one function to another as you suggested, but the problem remains. moreover now also the counter (counter) does not work properly.